# Showing Images in Array coding for Javascript on Blogging sites

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, blogs

On my blog I have a html coding for array. I downloaded this blogskin from the website blogskins and it came with the coding "array". I'm sort of familiar with this but I have no idea in the html code I was wondering if you guys can help me?
The coding I got is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide
numquotes = 3;
var quotes = new Array(numquotes);
quotes[0]="<img src=http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i9.jpg>";
quotes[1]="<img src=http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i6.jpg>";
quotes[2]="<img src=http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i10.jpg>";
quotes[3]="<img src=http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i7.jpg>";
quotes[4]="<img src=http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i3.jpg>";
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*numquotes);
document.write(quotes[rand]);
// -->
</script></center>
```

I want to change those images to my own, and I have a couple of links I want to replace it, so instead of HeartsAloud it will read my username.

http://s1286.photobucket.com/user/Aquallurement/media/Blogger/tumblr_luufej9POE1r2jjy2o1_500_zpsecce3309.gif.html

^ an example like that, whenever I put that link instead of the one already there it never shows up when I save it.

It just randomizes pictures whenever you post an entry. Can anyone help? Am I using the wrong link?

Comment: which image? the one I gave as an example? If so, yes since I uploaded it yesterday. Whenever I put it in, it won't show.

Comment: I tried accessing above image direclty , its re-directing me to the different page , may be that is your web server configuration or may be you are missing something in the image URI

Comment: this one : http://i589.photobucket.com/albums/ss333/HeartsAloud/i3.jpg ?

Comment: sorry my bad, image is displaying properly!! try to see if your script is being executed by adding alert('test') after document.write() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your modified version would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide
numquotes = 5;
var quotes = new Array(numquotes);
quotes[0]='<img src="YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES">';
quotes[1]='<img src="YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES">';
quotes[2]='<img src="YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES">';
quotes[3]='<img src="YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES">';
quotes[4]='<img src="YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES">';
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*numquotes);
document.write(quotes[rand]);
// -->
</script>
```

so you replace the YOUR LINK GOES HERE BETWEEN THE QUOTES with your link to get:

```
quotes[0]='<img src="http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a601/Aquallurement/Blogger/tumblr_luufej9POE1r2jjy2o1_500_zpsecce3309.gif">';
```

make sure you are linking to the image directly, not the photobucket page (right click on the image and select copy image URL in google chrome)

this is the link you posted:
http://s1286.photobucket.com/user/Aquallurement/media/Blogger/tumblr_luufej9POE1r2jjy2o1_500_zpsecce3309.gif.html

this is the link of the image, you should be using:
http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a601/Aquallurement/Blogger/tumblr_luufej9POE1r2jjy2o1_500_zpsecce3309.gif

Comment: yes I did that, however it won't show! Am I using the wrong link?

Comment: make sure you are linking to the image directly, right click on it in photobucket and then select copy image URL

Comment: How will I do that? LOL I'm sorry

Comment: you click on the hook so that it turns green right to the left of the answer, underneath where these two arrows are with the zero inbetween...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the built-in string functions, like replace?

```
 var str="Visit Microsoft!";
 var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

from: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

so in your case it would be something like:

```
 newLink = quotes[0].replace('old_userame', 'your_username')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really good with this. Where would I put that? and what would I replace it with.

Comment: so I would do quotes[0].replace="<img src=http://s1286.photobucket.com/user/Aquallurement/media/Blogger/tumblr_luufej9POE1r2jjy2o1_500_zpsecce3309.gif.html>"; ?

Comment: so you would do something along the lines of this: quotes[0] = quotes[0].replace('old_userame', 'your_username') 
or do you want to change the entire link?

Comment: I would like to change the entire link, because the link in the code I provided shows an image. I want to change that image with my own link an example would be this one : http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a601/Aquallurement/Blogger/tumblr_lzqzx39ICN1qhwuczo1_500_zpsc15c1b16.jpg